# Select não atualiza os dados da tabela após selecionar uma opção

Tags: jquery, html-select, web-scraping, web-crawler

Estou tentando selecionar o campo  com essa query no entanto o valor do select é alterado mas não recarrega os valores da tabela, mostrando todos. Mas clicando com o mouse, funciona.

```
document.getElementsByName("tbResult_length")[0].selectedIndex = 4
```

Essa é a página.
[Tabela CNAE](https://cnae.ibge.gov.br/?view=classe&tipo=cnae&versao=10&classe=03221)

Answer (score 0):

Precisamos de mais informação.

Mais acredito que o problema está no evento disparado na hora da seleção.

Qual tecnologia você está utilizando para crawlear?

Geralmente quando a interações com outros campos essa só ocorre quando um determinado evento é disparado, acredito que seja isso que esteje faltando.

Por exemplo:

```
function simularInputEventol() {
  var input = document.getElementById('Elemento a Ser Atribuido Valor');
  var ev = new Event('change');

  input.value ='teste';
  input.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

Só tem que descobrir qual evento é necessário.